# Best Method to pause a Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, thread-sleep

I have a Runnable class which performs an operation continuously in its run method using an infinite while loop. Sometimes a user might want to pause/resume the operation. What is the best method to pause the Thread. I have two thoughts:

**FIRST**

```
class Foo extends Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    while(true) {
        if(pauseFlag)
           try{
              Thread.sleep();
           } catch(InterrruptedException ie) {//...}
    }
}
```

**SECOND**

```
class Foo extends Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            //pause if user wants to pause
            while(pauseFlag);
        }
    }
}
```

- In the **FIRST** case, when i use Thread.sleep inside loop the Netbeans IDE issues warning not to use Thread.sleep inside loop. Why is that?
- In the **SECOND** case, when i use infinite empty while loop, is that a performance overhead?
- Which method(mentioned above or otherwise) should i prefer to pause the action being performed by the Thread according to the users choice?

Because it has nothing to do with synchronization, i do not want to use wait/notify.

Comment: I wouldn't program a `Thread` for it to pause. Implement it to wait on something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the FIRST case, when i use Thread.sleep inside loop the Netbeans IDE issues warning not to use Thread.sleep inside loop. Why is that?

I guess because Netbeans thinks that it won't be testing the loop condition and the code will pause unnecessarily.

> In the SECOND case, when i use infinite empty while loop, is that a performance overhead?

Uh yes.  Spinning a thread will take a CPU and be a performance sink.

> Which method(mentioned above or otherwise) should i prefer to pause the action being performed by the Thread according to the users choice?

Neither?  I would use a `volatile boolean pauseFlag` for testing if the thread should pause,  combined with wait/notify to unpause it.  Or you can use an `AtomicBoolean` which wraps a `volatile boolean` but is also an object we can synchronize on.  Maybe something like:

```
// using `AtomicBoolean` which wraps a `volatile boolean` but is const object
// NOTE: we _can't_ synchronized on Boolean, needs to be constant object reference
private final AtomicBoolean pauseFlag = new AtomicBoolean(false);
...
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    if (pauseFlag.get()) {
       synchronized (pauseFlag) {
          // we are in a while loop here to protect against spurious interrupts
          while (pauseFlag.get())) {
             try {
                pauseFlag.wait();
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                // we should probably quit if we are interrupted?
                return;
             }
          }
       }
    }
    ...
}
...
public void pause() {
   pauseFlag.set(true);
}
...
public void resume() {
   pauseFlag.set(false);
   synchronized (pauseFlag) {
       pauseFlag.notify();
   }
}
```

I guess if I were forced to pick from one of the two, I would pick the `sleep(...)` loop.  Even `sleep(1)` is significantly better than a spin.  Do you really need to un-pause quicker than ~1ms?  But the wait/notify is the most efficient.

> Because it has nothing to do with synchronization, i do not want to use wait/notify.

As mentioned by @Jon, some sort of synchronization is necessary here since you are trying to communicate between two threads.  Certainly you need to have memory synchronization otherwise any updates to `pauseFlag` will not be guaranteed to be shared between threads.  This is handled by the `volatile` primitive on `pauseFlag`.  By using wait/notify (which needs `synchronized`) your code can be much more efficient about the wakeup.

Answer (score 3):

> Because it has nothing to do with synchronization, i do not want to use wait/notify.

It has *everything* to do with synchronization. Presumably your user interaction occurs on a different thread - so you're trying to synchronize signals between the two threads.

You shouldn't use `Thread.sleep` *or* a tight loop here. Either `wait`/`notify` or something similar using a higher-level construct in `java.util.concurrent` is the right approach here.

Note that without any memory barriers, changes to your `pauseFlag` from one thread may not be noticed in a different thread, so you'd *at least* want to make it volatile.

Comment: if i use java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger to use as a flag even then i would loose CPU cycles with tight loop. Should i use a wait/notify or tight loop?

Comment: @Madeyedexter: I didn't suggest using `AtomicInteger`, did I? I suggested using a higher level threading construct from `java.util.concurrent` (e.g. `Semaphore`) or `wait`/`notify`. You definitely *shouldn't* perform a tight loop.

Comment: Ok. I will see to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are synchronizing a state change between threads so I would use wait(), however the alternative is to use a sleep.  You could busy wait, but you wouldn't gain much but you would lose a CPU.